# Error in uno platform auto generated file and program.cs - only on Mac

Tags: uno-platform

I have a simple app based un uno platform. On Windows I can build and run it without any problem. But on VS for Mac the compiler gives error to the auto generated RemoteControl.g.cs file:

- Error CS0826: No best type found for implicitly-typed array (CS0826)
  (UnoTeszt.Wasm)
- Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from '?[]'
  to 'string[]' (CS1503) (UnoTeszt.Wasm)

```
// <auto-generated>
// ***************************************************************************************
// This file has been generated by the package Uno.UI.RemoteControl - for Xaml Hot Reload.
// Documentation: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/working-with-xaml-hot-reload.html
// ***************************************************************************************
// </auto-generated>
// <autogenerated />
#pragma warning disable // Ignore code analysis warnings

[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("fe80::1%1", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("fe80::109d:3e33:34e7:51fb%4", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("10.111.111.61", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("fe80::5805:f7ff:feaa:6ec3%8", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("fe80::5805:f7ff:feaa:6ec3%9", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("fe80::1d3:92b1:ff7d:cf5%10", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ServerEndpointAttribute("fe80::77d1:f7a1:4393:622b%11", 0)]
[assembly: global::Uno.UI.RemoteControl.ProjectConfigurationAttribute(
@"/Users/kistelekig/Documents/Vitarex/FilmesApp/UnoTeszt/UnoTeszt/UnoTeszt.Wasm/UnoTeszt.Wasm.csproj",

new[]{}
)]
```

And I have an other problem as well in the Program.cs:

[...]/UnoTeszt/UnoTeszt.Wasm/Program.cs(20,20): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (UnoTeszt.Wasm)

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace UnoTeszt.Wasm
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static App _app;

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
      Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start(_ => _app = new App());

      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I have the latest version of VS for Mac and MacOS installed.

Comment: Hi, what version of Uno.UI are you using so I can try to replicate it on my side?

Comment: The same thing for me. Can not compile a template installed via dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when there's no XAML files tagged as `<Page />` in your project. Make sure to correctly reference your shared project.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root issue. When I create a project via dotnet new:

```
dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet
dotnet new unoapp -o App-CrossPlatform
```

I have the next shared project

```
App-CrossPlatform\App-CrossPlatform.Shared\App-CrossPlatform.Shared.shproj
App-CrossPlatform\App-CrossPlatform.Shared\App-CrossPlatform.Shared.projitems
```

But in other (android, ios) projects there are the next imports:

```
  <Import Project="..\App_CrossPlatform.Shared\App_CrossPlatform.Shared.projitems" Label="Shared" Condition="Exists('..\App_CrossPlatform.Shared\App_CrossPlatform.Shared.projitems')" />
```

Yes... Symbol `-` vs `_`...

I have created an issue:
https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/4217